# Power automate auto deleting flow variable

Tags: power-automate

I am experiencing a weird bug, or maybe a problem in my code, and I was wondering if any one knew a solution. I have a flow that pulls information from a google sheet to automatically send an email. The fields are as shown below in the first image. However, when I try to save the worfkle the "If choosing a sweater/T-shirt, what size?" variable is being removed as can be seen in the second image.

Please let me know if you have a possible solution for this!

Image 1
[image: Worfklow prior to save]

Image 2
[image: Flow after save]

Hi All Edit: Please see the code view available to me.

```
{
  "type": "OpenApiConnection",
  "inputs": {
    "parameters": {
      "emailMessage/To": "tharsika@greenhouse.ca",
      "emailMessage/Subject": "Delivery Gift Order ",
      "emailMessage/Body": "<p><span style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">Hi Rob, Below is details for a gift order.</span></p><p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">Who are you gifting? - </strong></b>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r123301d4b1ab437cbc206f68f4030de5']}</p><p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">What is this for? -</strong></b><span style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\"> </span>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rd0ee2cf03bcc4c518114aa310359a06e']}</p><p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">Greenhouse Swag to include in the gift. - </strong></b>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r3d2897c219fc47109de6df7f31fc70dc']}</p><p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">Greenhouse's Greatest Hits -</strong></b><span style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\"> </span>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r4a87ebf316ac4b5e9c5b8bc8f5c10190']}</p><p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">If choosing a sweater/T - Shirt, what size? - </strong></b><span id=\"\"></span></p><p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">Delivery Option - </strong></b>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rb23641480b9a40239bca1877ceac5760']}</p><p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">Phone number of gift recipient. -</strong></b><span style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\"> </span>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rf18fbbf9357d462596bba0031913019c']}</p><p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">Delivery Address -</strong></b><span style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\"> </span>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r2fd26a7e41454095b0233b463125f06f']}</p><p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">Deliver Instructions -</strong></b><span style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\"> </span>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r0262ff0c942549cfa956d3ed9e294938']}</p><p><span style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">Thank you,</span></p>",
      "emailMessage/Importance": "Normal"
    },
    "host": {
      "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365",
      "connection": "shared_office365",
      "operationId": "SendEmailV2"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Get_response_details": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  },
  "metadata": {
    "operationMetadataId": "a57c88a0-9a01-460f-b781-2cae2d33ce92"
  }
}
```

Comment: That expression is different to the others, can you show us the code view and give us the JSON from that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the expression is missing in the code view in that specific paragraph (`<p></p>`). Your HTML might be broken.

```
<p><b><strong style=\"white-space: pre-wrap;\">If choosing a sweater/T - Shirt, what size? - </strong></b><span id=\"\"></span></p>
```

Can you remove the If choosing field from the Body and add it back again to see if that fixes the html in the code view?